# Expected Azure App Service Size to Host my API as Production environment

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

I have created an .Net core 7. Expected concurrent user count is 2000 at any time. Request size 1 KB, response size 5 KB. What App service tier Standard? Premium? is more suitable? How do i map it with ACU? My traffic is not burstable. Almost zero traffic in nights.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-general

Answer (score 0):

If we host the app on azure app service. We can implement this requirement by enable [Automatic scaling in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal).

Azure platform managed scale up and down based on traffic.

For more questions about scaling web apps, you can check [this FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/scaling-web-app-faq).